# How to find the source of library files

Tags: centos, package-management

I'm using Centos 7 and I have got one library file "libtrs.so" so how can I know what is the incoming source of that file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file came from a package,

```
rpm -qif /path/to/libtrs.so
```

will tell you which package, and will show you the information it has about that package (including its upstream URL, if any).

If that doesn’t show any package, that means the file was installed manually somehow. The system won’t be able to tell you where it came from. You can look at the file’s timestamps with

```
stat /path/to/libtrs.so
```

and perhaps look through the various shell history files to see if you can find a trace of it...

Comment: I have done already. it is not showing any package.